# Postgis st_intersects not selecting correct features

Tags: postgis, st-intersects

I am running a very simple boolean selection with `postgis st_intersects` on two polygon tables:

```
select distinct on(ms.shape) ms.shape shape,ms.type_ 
    from riparian_corridor.merged_soils ms join riparian_corridor.riparian_open_waters o 
        on st_intersects(ms.shape,o.shape);
```

This query returns most correct features but there are a handful of instances where the features clearly intersect and it is not selected.

The distance between the edge of that blue feature and red outline polygon is about 2 feet. Should I be using `st_snaptogrid`? If so, which geometry should I put it on? and should the tolerance be something around 2 feet to pick those features up?

[image]

Comment: What about: select ms.shape,ms.type_ 
    from riparian_corridor.merged_soils ms
where ST_Intersects(ms.shape, (select shape from riparian_corridor.riparian_open_waters o));

Comment: 1. ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
********** Error ********** 2. why would this work better? 3. using st_union on the riparian_open_waters would take forever, its a massive table

Comment: Ok, yeah. I'm just thinking perhaps the distinct is removing some of the joins. Try: select ms.shape,ms.type_ 
    from riparian_corridor.merged_soils ms join riparian_corridor.riparian_open_waters o 
        on st_intersects(ms.shape,o.shape);

Comment: Or simply check if PostGIS really does not find intersection between those geometries or if there is some glitch in your query `select st_intersects(ms.shape,o.shape) where ms.id=xx and o.id=yy`

Comment: @user30184 good idea il give that a shot

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto I think you were correct the distinct on clause was removing some joins, I will post what ended up working for me

Comment: @ziggy this question has been flagged for closure so once you have an answer to post, can you flag us so that it can be re-opened to post that, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@HeikkiVesanto led me in the right direction with removing the distinct on clause, I believe that was removing some features from my query (still exactly unsure how)

but the query that ended up doing the trick was

```
select distinct shape from(
    select ms.shape shape 
    from riparian_corridor.merged_soils ms join riparian_corridor.riparian_open_waters o 
        on st_intersects(ms.shape,o.shape))t  ;
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to put shape in a DISTINCT ON clause.  It would be the bounding box of the geometry it's distincting.

Use a different field like gid or if you really want to go by geometry do something like DISTINCT ON(ms.shape::text)

Comment: the merged soils table has many duplicate geometries, I am aware the distinct on uses a bounding box to collapse them but I would still need to distinct them/group them down (want to avoid st_union because these tables are so large).

Comment: okay then cast your geometry to text as I mentioned using  ms.shape::text  will then group by the hex representation of the geometry.  You can also use ST_AsBinary(ms.shape)